# How to extract multiple json values from a Json response

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to extract multiple values from a JSON response on my jmeter script. Below is sample of my response:

{
                "startDate": "2018-12-10T15:36:34.400+0000",
                "userId": "7211111-2fa90",
            "createdBy": "TEST",
                "note": {
                    "content": "Application Submitted "
                },
                "Type": "SUBMITTED"
            },

```
    "currentEventState": "CLOSED",
     {
        "Xxxx": "test",
        "Loc": null,
        "Zipcode": [],
        "Locality": 82,
        "Address": {
            "Add": 12302,
            "Add2": "place",
            "Zip": {
                "Phone": "home",
                "Email": "test@test.com"
            }
        },
        "state": "MD",
        "Cost": "E  "
    },
    "AppID": "cd8d98e6-c2a79",
    "Status": "CLOSED",

}
```

I am trying  to extract userid and AppID for the case if the TYPE is Submitted and Status is Closed.I tried using the Json extractor with `$.[?(@.Type=="SUBMITTED")].[*].?(@.Status=="CLOSED").userid,APPID`, but couldn't get the expected result. Could anyone guide me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an [inline predicate](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#inline-predicates) to combine 2 clausees and a semicolon in order to store results into 2 separate JMeter Variables.

1. Add [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns above JSON
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Names of created variables: `userid;appid`
   - JSON Path Expressions: `$..[?(@.Type=='SUBMITTED' && @.Status == 'CLOSED')].userId; $..[?(@.Type=='SUBMITTED' && @.Status == 'CLOSED')].AppID`
   - Default values: `NA;NA`

Here is the demo of single expression working fine:

[image]

And here are extracted values reported by the [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input, my response output is having  multiple  blocks when i tried the above solution i keep on getting the NA